# PHP Database update is not working

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I have this code and it gives my a Error 500. I am trying to make it so that it will change the profile picture.

```
<?php
include_once("dbConnect.php");
include_once("indexinfo.php");
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("DATABASE);
if(isset($_POST['imagelink'])) {
    $imagelink = "SELECT `username` UPDATE `TEST` SET `picture` = '$_POST['imagelink']' WHERE username = '$_SESSION['username']'";
    mysqli_query($dbCon, $imagelink);
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove the quotes inside `username` in `'$_SESSION['username']'"` and also `['imagelink']` and make sure `session_start();` is loaded. Yet this method is open to SQL injection. Or use `'".$_POST['imagelink']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";`

Comment: So like  $_SESSION[username]

Comment: I edited my comment above, reload it.

Comment: I think, before you do any of this, you should learn to look at the server error log which will tell you precisely what your problem is.

Comment: How to i look at the server logs

Comment: You also have a missing quote `mysqli_connect("DATABASE);` --- `mysqli_connect("DATABASE");` which is the main cause for your 500 error. Yet, what I don't get is this `include_once("dbConnect.php");` then you're doing `$dbCon = mysqli_connect...` what's inside that file?

Comment: it still gives me an error

Comment: what's inside your included files?

Comment: **Wait a minute,** you can't select and update at the same time. Remove the `SELECT username` - I just noticed that now.

Comment: 'apache logs = /usr/local/apache/logs'

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can't use `SELECT` and `UPDATE` at the same time; it's one or the other. In your case, use only `UPDATE` with the table you wish to update.

```
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("DATABASE");
if(isset($_POST['imagelink'])) {
    $imagelink = "UPDATE `TEST` SET `picture` = '".$_POST['imagelink']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    mysqli_query($dbCon, $imagelink);
}
```

Plus, make sure `session_start();` is loaded. I don't know what's inside your two included files or where your session variable is coming from, but this is how you will need to do it. See my notes below.

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo)

---

**Footnotes:**

You may also want to use, if that's not what you're presently using, which is hard to tell at the moment.

```
$dbCon=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```